# CLion with Cygwin: g++.exe .../compiler-arguments.txt: No such file or directory error

Tags: c++, cygwin, clion

In CLion using Cygwin, when I try to open a certain c++ project, I get the following error when parsing the project's CMake file:

```
Error:Configuration emdw [Debug]
Compiler exited with error code 1: g++ -xc++ -Demdw_EXPORTS -I/cygdrive/c/Users/Dirk/.CLion2016.2/system/cmake/generated/emdw-e21eebc3/e21eebc3/Debug/src -I/cygdrive/f/devel/emdw/src -I/cygdrive/f/devel -I/cygdrive/f/devel/patrecII/src -std=c++11 -O3 -g -Wall -v -dD -E
g++.exe: error: @/cygdrive/f/users/heetbeet/AppData/Local/Temp/compiler-arguments.txt: No such file or directory
g++.exe: error: /cygdrive/f/users/heetbeet/AppData/Local/Temp/compiler-file: No such file or directory
g++.exe: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
```

I take it CLion generate these type of compiler-arguments.txt / compiler-file files, since no such instructions are found in the actual CMake structure. Note that I can successfully run `cmake.exe` on this project from Cygwin's bash without any errors.

What magic is CLion trying to achieve with the `compiler-arguments.txt` file (if it is CLion), and how do I begin to debug this problem?

I can confirm that upon clicking the `Reload CMake Project` button in CLion,

[image]

two files named `compiler-arguments.txt` and `compiler-file` are indeed created in `F:\users\heetbeet\AppData\Local\Temp` (that is `/cygdrive/f/users/heetbeet/AppData/Local/Temp/` in Cygwin).

The content of `compiler-arguments.txt` is:

```
-xc++ -Demdw_EXPORTS -I/cygdrive/c/Users/Dirk/.CLion2016.2/system/cmake/generated/emdw-e21eebc3/e21eebc3/Debug/src -I/cygdrive/f/devel/emdw/src -I/cygdrive/f/devel -I/cygdrive/f/devel/patrecII/src -std=c++11 -O3 -g -Wall -v -dD -E -D___CIDR_IGNORE_DEFINITIONS_START
```

The `compiler-file` contains a bunch of `#if`'s, `#ifdef`'s, with the first 20 lines as:

```
#define ___CIDR_IGNORE_DEFINITIONS_END
#if !(defined (__has_extension)) && defined(__has_feature)
  #define __has_extension __has_feature
#endif
#if !defined(__has_attribute)
  #define __has_attribute(x) 0
#endif
#ifdef __has_feature
#if __has_feature(cxx_constexpr)
____CIDR_test_query_feature->cxx_constexpr=1
#else
____CIDR_test_query_feature->cxx_constexpr=0
#endif
#if __has_feature(cxx_trailing_return)
____CIDR_test_query_feature->cxx_trailing_return=1
#else
____CIDR_test_query_feature->cxx_trailing_return=0
#endif
#if __has_feature(c_generic_selections)
____CIDR_test_query_feature->c_generic_selections=1
<...>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to create AST of your source files somehow. To make it right we need the compiler-specific macros and features FOR EACH c/cpp-file in your project, because you can change the compiler option for each one. So that is the price you are paying for right highlighting and macro evaluation in cross-platform project.

About the issue: you are using cygwin and I have feeling that the problem can be resolved by chmod 777 calls.

Comment: Thanks @uta. Now that I think about it, either my Cygwin or my "Administrator" has been generating files with strange permissions lately. So you think it is a file-permission problem.

Comment: Yes, that is my assumption. The mixture of POSIX and WIN32 is worse. Be sure that you have only one "unix" subsystem in the path (Mingw xor cygwin xor power shell). And nether change the account for project (or evaluated privileges) while you are working with cygwin. The result is unpredictable due to "unusual" ACL/DACL in files that are written by cygwin utils.

Comment: Thanks, I screwed up file permissions because I ran Clion (or Cygwin, can't exactly remember) as administrator. Don't ask me why I was that stupid. Thanks for your eagle eyes in spotting the problem, I will be more strict in my use of run-as-administrator in the future!

Comment: @SimonStreicher I'm running into a very similar issue. Would you mind giving a little more detail on how you resolved the issue? Thanks!

Comment: Hi Chad, if I remember correctly (I should have documented my fix better), my Cygwin is a throw-away I don't care for much, so I ran it from administrator and did a chmod 777 recursively to the whole cygwin file system (from Cygwin bash), and to all the Clion appdata files, and to all the files in my c++ project. I think I might also have done the Windows equivalent to chmod 777 on those files as well. I basically scrubbed all privileges from all the associated file. Living on the edge!